# Change element css with jQuery without using classes or ids?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say we have unknown number of div elements. When we click on the element that element must change its background color. How to do that **without** using *classes* or *ids*.

*NOTE: I found some questions with similar topic but they were not what I was looking for.*

I mean smth like:

```
$(element).click(
    function(){
       $(element).css("background-color","#DDDDDD");
    }
);
```

HTML:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
height:10px;
width:10px;
float:left;
border-radius:50%;
margin:2px;
background-color:#00A2E8;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ooyjLsy4/)

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/ooyjLsy4/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pretty close, just refer to the element itself in the function.

```
$("div").on("click",
    function(){
       $(this).css("background-color","#DDDDDD");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
$('div').click(function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', '#DDDDDD');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ooyjLsy4/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "[this](https://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified)" in jquery to accomplish what you are asking.

```
$('div').click(
    function(){
      $(this).css("background-color","{{Your Color}}");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all elements of a certain type, you can directly just use their names `$('div')`, `$('a')`, `$('span')`, etc.

If you have an event (`click`, `mouseover`, `change`, etc.), you can access to the specific control that fires that event by just using `$(this)` within that event block.

Therefore you should have this:

```
$('div').click(
    function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","#DDDDDD");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the element selector in jquery. Simply do $("div") to select all div elements. More information on selectors can be found at [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp).